# Monit can not start thrift

Tags: thrift, monit

Here's my code below:

```
check host thrift with address 127.0.0.1
if failed port 9090 type tcp
then exec "/bin/bash -c '/bin/lib/hbase/bin/hbase-daemon.sh start thrift'"
```

The first two lines can be executed as I expected, but the last line is executed without error and starting thrift, like doing nothing.

By the way, these command above can be run in bash and the command start thrift as I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, Monit can not start thrift because the different between environments. Just make sure that the environments required is being set.